# Closing apache CloseableHttpConnection and properly handle closing exception

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

According to the Apache [documentation](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/fundamentals.html#d5e206), whenever you open a `CloseableHttpClient`, you must also close it. However, the close method of `CloseableHttpClientthrows` an `IOException`. I cannot find any word in the docs about this exception. What could possible be a reason of a connection close to fail? What should I do in this case?

```
private void someMethod(){

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost post = createPostRequest(); //some custom build request.

    HttpResponse response;

    try{
        response = httpClient.execute(post);
    }catch(Exception e){
        handleException(e);
    }finally{
        try{
            httpClient.close()
        }catch(IOException e){
            //WHAT TO DO HERE ?!?!?
        }
    }
    doSomethingWith(response);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is required to process `IOException` because `IOException` will never happen.

TL;DR;
`CloseableHttpClient` is abstract class and it implements interface `Closeable`. As you can see, `Closeable::close` method declares `throws IOException`, but `CloseableHttpClient` leave it to be abstract method. Thus, subclasses of `CloseableHttpClient` should take care of implementation.

`HttpClients::createDefault` returns `InternalHttpClient` which implements `Closeable::close` method without `throws` declaration at all.